# nodejs control json name

Tags: json, node.js, stringify

I've a function that gets 2 values **name** and **value** and now I'd like to turn them into a JSON, so for example lets say ive this function

```
function addin(name,val)
```

and then i'll call it

```
addin("age","28") -> this will return -> {age: 28}
addin("name","Roni") -> {name: Roni}
```

I've tried many things to find out how to make it done, Im getting many data so I tried this

```
var full_js = { };

    _.forEach(data, function(val,name) {

        full_js.name = val;
        console.log(JSON.stringify(full_js));

    });
```

again it can be any value and any name **both of them are Random Strings**.
but its not working, I get it as {"name": "Roni"} and {"name": "55"}.
thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a different notation:

```
function addin(name, val) {
    var full_js = {};
    full_js[name] = val;

    return JSON.stringify(full_js);
}
```

Ex:

[image]

at the moment you are always assigning the value to the `name` key, instead of the dynamic name key, keep in mind that the key will always be the string representation of the variable used.

for example, `addin({}, 'rony')`, will return `{"[object Object]":"test"}`